# Передача двумерного массива в функцию C++

Tags: c++

При компиляции выдает следующее:

```
prog.cpp: In function 'int main()':
prog.cpp:46:37: error: cannot convert 'int (*)[n]' to 'int**' for argument '4' to 'void dfs(int, std::vector<int>&, int, int**)'
     dfs(1, used, n, Adjacency_matrix);
                                     ^
```

Как я понимаю, проблема с передачей двумерного массива в функцию. Что надо изменить для того, чтобы разрешить проблему? (Код приведен ниже.) Конкретнее: массив **Adjacency_matrix** передается в функцию **dfs**.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>

void dfs(int i, std::vector <int> &used, int n, int (&Adjacency_matrix)[n][n]) {
    used[i] = 1;
    for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
        if ((Adjacency_matrix[i][j] == 1) && (used[j] == 0))
            dfs(j, used, n, Adjacency_matrix);
    }
}

double distance(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
    return sqrt((x1 - x2)*(x1 - x2) + (y1 - y2)*(y1 - y2));
}

int main() {
    int n, k;
    std::cin >> n >> k;

    int coordinates[n][2];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        std::cin >> coordinates[i][1];
        std::cin >> coordinates[i][2];
    }

    int Adjacency_matrix[n][n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
            if (i == j)
                Adjacency_matrix[i][i] = 0;
            if ((i != j) && (distance(coordinates[i][1], coordinates[i][2], coordinates[j][1], coordinates[j][2]) <= k))
                Adjacency_matrix[i][j] = 1;
            if ((i != j) && (distance(coordinates[i][1], coordinates[i][2], coordinates[j][1], coordinates[j][2]) > k))
                Adjacency_matrix[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }

    std::vector <int> used;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        used.push_back(0);

    dfs(1, used, n, Adjacency_matrix);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        if (used[i] == 0)
            std::cout << "NO";
            exit(0);
    }
    std::cout << "YES";
}
```

Comment: Насколько понимаю, функция предполагает передачу массива целиком (если честно, я с такой записью не встречался), а в конце вы пытаетесь передать отдельный элемент.

Comment: Да, в конце я ошибся, сейчас подправлю, но появилась новая ошибка, тоже сейчас укажу

Comment: @Hashirama, а вот в gcc (Си) подобный код


    void f (int n, int a[][n]) {
      for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) // печатаем диагональ
        printf("%d\n", a[i][i]);
    }
    
    int main (int ac, char *av[]) {
      int n;

      scanf("%d", &n);
      int  a[n][n];
      f(n, a);
      ...

вполне допустим, т.е. размерность матрицы можно передавать в аргументах функции.

Comment: @Hashirama, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

В C++ можно выкрутиться вот в таком духе

```
void f (int n, int *a[])
{
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    printf("%d\n", a[i][i]); // печатаем диагональ
}

int main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  int n;
  cin >> n;
  int *a[n];
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    a[i] = new int[n];
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      a[i][j] = i + j; // вообще-то тут инициализируете свою "матрицу"
    }
  }

  f(n, a);

 // в конце надо вручную освобождать память
 for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
   delete [] a[i];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Насколько помню, при работе с n-мерными массивами нужны n-мерные указатели.

Comment: Спасибо!
А Вы не могли подсказать как это выглядит?